# How to find total time of employee in the office using Pyspark considering and removing out and in time difference

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

## Sample data

```
    Eid, TS, Event
    1,2020-12-30T09:00:00, IN
    1,2020-12-30T13:00:00, OUT
    1,2020-12-30T14:00:00, IN
    1,2020-12-30T17:00:00, OUT
    1,2020-12-30T17:30:00, IN
    1,2020-12-30T20:00:00, OUT
    2,2020-12-30T10:30:00, IN
    2,2020-12-30T15:00:00, OUT
    2,2020-12-30T16:30:00, IN
    2,2020-12-30T21:30:00, IN
    2,2020-12-30T22:30:00, OUT
    1,2020-12-31T09:00:00, IN
    1,2020-12-31T13:00:00, OUT
    1,2020-12-31T14:00:00, IN
    1,2020-12-31T17:00:00, OUT
    1,2020-12-31T17:30:00, IN
    1,2020-12-31T20:00:00, OUT
    2,2020-12-31T10:30:00, IN
    2,2020-12-31T15:00:00, OUT
    2,2020-12-31T16:30:00, IN
    2,2020-12-31T21:30:00, IN
    2,2020-12-31T23:30:00, OUT
```

## My approach

```
# In[1]
#reading the file
df = spark.read.csv('lag_lead.csv',inferSchema=True,header=True)
df.show(100,False)
        
        
# In[2]:
    
df = df.withColumn('r_Date',col('ts').cast(DateType()))\
       .withColumn('new_ts',col('ts').cast('long'))
                    
# In[3]:
from pyspark.sql.window import *
df = df.withColumn('leading',(lead('new_ts').over(Window.partitionBy('eid','r_Date').orderBy(col('ts')))-col('new_ts')))
    
df.show(100,False)
df = df.withColumn('leading',when(col('event')=='OUT',col('leading')*-1).otherwise('leading'))

# In[4]:
df=df.groupBy('eid','event','ts','r_Date')\
     .agg(sum('leading').alias('sum_leading'))\
     .select('eid', 'event', 'ts', 'r_date', lit(col('sum_leading')/3600).alias('sum_leading'))
    
df = df.withColumn('find_total',(col('ts').cast('long')-lag(col('ts').cast('long'))
                                .over(Window.partitionBy('eid','r_date').orderBy('ts')))/3600)\
       .fillna(0,subset=('find_total','sum_leading'))
       
# In[5]:
df = df.withColumn('final_total_hrs',col('find_total')+col('sum_leading'))
df.groupBy('eid','r_date').agg(sum('final_total_hrs').alias('spent_hrs')).show()
```

## Output

```
    eid|  r_date  |spent_hrs
      2|2020-12-31|     11.5
      1|2020-12-31|      9.5
      2|2020-12-30|     10.5
      1|2020-12-30|      9.5
```

Question
What is the optimized way of doing above solution?
Approach
Using lead to find difference of value,
converted the timestamp to long because difference of timestamp is an
interval type and then took a sum of the values.
Can anyone help me getting the code optimized with less line of code.

Comment: i think you have the good approach

Comment: Hey steven thanks for confirmation,

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# read the data into a PySpark DataFrame
data = spark.read.csv("path/to/file.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)

# convert the timestamp column from string to timestamp datatype
data = data.withColumn("TS", to_timestamp(col("TS"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))

# create a new column called "duration" which stores the time difference between the IN and OUT events for each employee on a given day
windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("Eid", date_trunc("day", "TS")).orderBy("TS")
data = data.withColumn("prev_TS", lag("TS", 1).over(windowSpec))
data = data.withColumn("prev_Event", lag("Event", 1).over(windowSpec))
df = df.withColumn("duration", 
               when(col("Event") == "IN", 0)
               .otherwise(when(col("prev_Event") == "OUT", 0)
               .otherwise(unix_timestamp(col("TS")) - unix_timestamp(col("prev_TS")))))


# group the DataFrame by employee ID and day and sum the duration column to get the total time spent in the office for each employee on each day
result = data.groupBy("Eid", date_trunc("day", "TS").alias("day")).agg(sum("duration").alias("total_time"))
result.show()
```